# Java process printing thread dump

Tags: java, thread-dump

I started a java process and it seems to be running fine. It is also working according to expectations. But every now and then it prints this thread dump. I am not sure if it is having some problems (memory?). Can anyone tell me what are the possible reasons for a java process to print thread dumps on its own?

Here is the thread dump. https://gist.github.com/tispratik/270869e17aaaf0d1b092

Comment: Maybe you have some sort of profiler running or something?

Comment: This java process seems to be running on a webserver?

Comment: A dump of all threads occurs in Unix/Linux whenever the java process receives a SIGQUIT.  In Windows, it occurs whenever the Ctrl-Break is pressed in the Java console window.

Comment: Yes its a java process running inside of Jetty. I am not giving the process a SIGQUIT signal.